# Elasticsearch : search document with conditional filter

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have two documents in my index (same type) :

```
{
    "first_name":"John",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "age":"24",
    "phone_numbers":[
        {
            "contract_number":"123456789",
            "phone_number":"987654321",
            "creation_date": ...
        },
        {
            "contract_number":"123456789",
            "phone_number":"012012012",
            "creation_date": ...
        }
    ]
}

{
    "first_name":"Roger",
    "last_name":"Waters",
    "age":"36",
    "phone_numbers":[
        {
            "contract_number":"546987224",
            "phone_number":"987654321",
            "creation_date": ...,
            "expired":true
        },
        {
            "contract_number":"87878787",
            "phone_number":"55555555",
            "creation_date": ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Clients would like to perform a **full text search**. Okay no problem here

My problem :
In this full text search, **sometimes** user will search by **phone_number**. In this case there is a **parameter** like `expired=true`.

Example :
First client search request : `"987654321"` with `expired` absent or set to `false`

--> Result : **Only first document**

Second client search request : `"987654321"` with `expired` set to `true`

--> Result : **The two documents**

How can I achieve that ?

Here is my mapping :

```
{
"user": {
    "_all": {
        "auto_boost": true,
        "omit_norms": true
    },
    "properties": {
        "phone_numbers": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "phone_number": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "creation_date": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "no"
                },
                "contract_number": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "expired": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                }
            }
        },
        "first_name":{
            "type": "string"
        },
        "last_name":{
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age":{
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}

}
```

Thanks !

MC

**EDIT :**

I tried this query :

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": "987654321",
                "analyze_wildcard": "true"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "phone_numbers",
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "should":[
                           {
                             "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                        "phone_number": "987654321"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "missing": {
                                        "field": "expired"
                                    }
                                }
                              ]
                            }       
                          },
                          {
                            "bool": {
                                "must_not": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "phone_number": "987654321"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }       
                         }
                        ]
                    }
                }
             }
        }
    }
}}
```

But I get the two documents instead of **get only the first one**

Comment: You want to have two different queries for above mentioned two cases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can i detect that the client performs a search on the phone_number field ? This is supposed to be a full text search without advanced features

Comment: You are getting 2 documents because both the conditions are satisfied.You have one document which has phone_number with missing expired field and one document with phone_number and expired field as true

Comment: What i tried to do in my query :
If the phone_number match then check if phone_number is expired then filter this document. 
If the phone_number does not match then don't filter the doc

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. Try using a combination of `must` and `should`, where the `must` clause ensures the `phone_number` matches the search value, and the `should` clause ensures that either the `expired` field is missing or set to `false`. For example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "987654321",
          "analyze_wildcard": "true"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "phone_numbers",
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "phone_number": "987654321"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "missing": {
                        "field": "expired"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "expired": false
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I ran this query using your mapping and sample documents and it returned the one document for John Doe, as expected.

Comment: What if the client perform this search : "John" ? The must clause does not match the case anymore.